# Telnet over a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, telnet

Im running OSX 10.10.5

Ive connected to a remote LAN via a dial in VPN.

For the VPN im using OSXs inbuilt VPN client and have the setting "send all traffic over VPN" enabled. The VPN works and i can communicate with the remote LAN as required, but i m having issues with a telnet connection.

I want to telnet into a device on the remote LAN via terminal to do this ive done the following :

`telnet $local_IP:$port`

And i get the following back in terminal

[image]

(Remote IP redacted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re not issuing the correct command. While a `host:port` notation is quite common in many programs, telnet is not one of those. Instead, replace the ":" with a space. So instead, type `telnet 192.168.14.29 52000`.

Comment: Thanks @Rob de Jonge very much that worked great ! Ive now connected to the device but all commands i send and responded to with "Error Command" even though im taking the codes straight out of the API docs, do i need to prefix the commands with anything to ensure that they are sent correctly ?

Comment: If you are connected, able to issue commands and getting feedback, then the VPN and telnet are doing their job. I have no idea what you’re connected to, and so I really can’t comment on what the right commands would be. I would suggest searching the web for some examples, instead of following API documentation. The experience of other users is usually much more helpful than dry manual pages. Good luck!